# How to quit job with consulting company but keep job with client?

Tags: united-states, clients, conflict-of-interest

I've been working with a consulting company on client site for almost two years, as a software engineer, specifically DevOps engineer who has done cool things like automated the integration/delivery process, among other things.

I just love the client and the app I work on. The consulting agency I work for, not so much and the main reason is that I find them to be incompetent and unreasonable (to be short). However, this company also "manages" the project, i.e. are not just a temp agency that places contractors to be managed by the client.

So I want to keep my job with the client but quit this consulting company. I am sure I am not the first person ever to want to do this and I am sure there are tried heuristics how to do it. For example, should I find another agency that is willing to represent me and that agency contacts the client with a proposal to disentangle my relationship with the present company and contract me through them or directly? Kind of like when a pro athlete hires a new manager.

I am asking for ideas because this may be a conflict of interest type of situation, however, I do not feel ethically compromised because I don't think the current company are providing quality service to their client and don't want to be associated with them -- without giving up the job and the client I really like. So I don't want to quit because I think it's them who are not good.

Comment: Do you have any non-compete or similar with your current consulting company?

Comment: This could also be a contractual issue, some agencies forbid you for working for that client/having them as a client or have non-compete clauses for an extended time after you leave.

Comment: yes, the other question is similar enough, thanks. you can close this.

Comment: You're right in that you're not the only person ever to want to do this and that's exactly why non-compete agreements exist.  Read the terms of your contract with your employer carefully before attempting this because there's a good chance you could get sued.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite likely that either your contract with the consulting company or the client's contract with consulting company will have clauses to prevent just this sort of scenario.

Your contract is easy enough for you to check but the client's will be harder - unless you have a contact there you can absolutely trust to stay discrete it can be a risk to even ask the question.

Even if there is no contractual restrictions in place the client may be hesitant to hire you as this would risk souring their relationship with the consulting company.